# How to resolve an infinity loop in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wanted to create a function that when it get's an error will go to a function named retry, retry will try the function again and if it gets wrong it will catch the error and to the retry process 5 times, if it doesn't pass it will throw the error. What i'm getting is an infinity loop because it awaits the fn and the fn has an error that calls retry, retry will await de fn again, so it never stops, how do i get it to go to the catch inside retry?

```js
async function retry(fn, retriesLeft = 5, interval = 1500) {
  try {
    return await fn();
  } catch (error) {
    if (retriesLeft) {
      console.log(`Error: ${error.message} | Retrying in ${interval} ms...`);
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, interval));
      return retry(fn, retriesLeft - 1, interval * 2);
    }
    throw error;
  }
}

function teste(retry) {
  try {
    throw Error
  } catch (error) {
    retry(teste)
  }
}

teste()
```

i tried changing the code and putting console.log on each steps to see how it goes, but it always do the same thing, it does the function teste, then the error makes it go to retry, but it never enters the catch inside retry, i need it to enter the ctach inside it, so the process can move on. I need this process because i'm trying to create a generic function that retry a process when it gets an error.

Comment: It's unclear why your `teste` function is an infinite loop, because your `retry` function is fine

Comment: The code shown immediately fails because in the initial call to `teste()` there is no provided value for `retry`, so it can't be called as a function.  Do you have an example which actually demonstrates the behavior you describe?

Comment: Hi guys i tried it using it as a callback and it works, but now the error says that retry is not a function, using the console.log it says that retry is undefined.

Comment: @AmandaScremin: Because `retry` is `undefined`.  When you call your function: `teste()`, what value do you expect the `retry` paramter to that function to have and why?  If you're expecting it to be your `retry` function, remove the `retry` parameter because it's *shadowing* that variable.

Answer (score 2):

What is happening is because the function you're passing to the `retry` function also has a catch block, which calls the `retry` function  again and again. I think your function works fine if the function you are passing as the first argument doesn't contain a `try catch`.
Try calling `retry` like this:

```
function teste() {
    throw new Error();
}

retry(teste);
```

Comment: I edited the post you are right it was very bad grammar and punctuation.

Answer (score -2):

Try the code below:

```
async function retry(fn, retriesLeft = 5, interval = 1500) {
  try {
    return await fn();
  } catch (error) {
    if (retriesLeft) {
      console.log(`Error: ${error.message} | Retrying in ${interval} ms...`);
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, interval));
      return retry(fn, retriesLeft - 1, interval * 2);
    }
    throw error;
  }
}

async function teste() {
  try {
    throw new Error('Test Error');
  } catch (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
}

retry(teste)
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Comment: Please express your answer in the form of code accompanied by an explanation (not as a game of spot-the-difference).

Comment: What was the problem with the original code?  What change did you make?  How does that solve the problem?